# Left join with view taking too much time in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2012, query-performance

This query is taking twenty seconds to display 53,000 records. This query has five left joins with views. But when I comment out the column `MAN.F_PHR AS MANU` in the select statement, it takes three seconds to display the 53,000 records.

How can I optimize this query? The view `V_PROD_ALIAS_MANU MAN` contains two left joins. The `MAN.F_PHRE AS MANU` column is from the view. Is there any way to optimize this query?

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    TP.PRODUCT AS ID,
    TP.NAME AS [NAME],
    TP.LANGUAGE AS LANGCODE,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR,TP.F_DATE_REVISED,120) AS RDATE,
    CASE
       WHEN NOT(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(TP.F_CAS_NUM,'¿',' '))),' ','; ') IS NULL OR REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(TP.F_CAS_NUM,'¿',' '))),' ','; ') = '') 
          THEN REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(TP.F_CAS_NUM,'¿',' '))),' ','; ') 
          ELSE REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(CASN.F_DATA,'¿',' '))),' ','; ')
    END AS CASNUM ,
    TP.F_CUSTOM1 AS cus1,
    TP.F_CUSTOM2 AS cus2,
    (SELECT TC.F_COUNTRY_NAME FROM COUNTRIES TC 
     WHERE TC.F_COUNTRY_CODE = TP.F_CUSTOM5) AS cus5,
    MAN.F_PHR AS MANU,
    CASE
       WHEN NOT(TP.F_CUSTOM3 IS NULL OR TP.F_CUSTOM3 = '') 
          THEN TP.F_CUSTOM3 
          ELSE SYN.F_DATA
    END AS SYN, 
    IC.F_DATA AS ICO,
    'SDS - ' + (SELECT TL.F_LAN_NAME FROM T_LANGUAGE TL 
                WHERE TL.F_LANGUAGE = TP.F_LANGUAGE) + ' - PDF' AS DOC,
    '' AS COVER,
    CAST(TP.F_GUID AS VARCHAR(36)) + '_PDF' AS [GUID],
    'PDF' AS SDS
FROM 
    PDF TP
LEFT JOIN 
    V_PROD_ALIAS_SYN SYN ON TP.F_PRODUCT = SYN.F_PRODUCT
LEFT JOIN 
    V_PROD_ALIAS_SITE SIT ON TP.F_PRODUCT = SIT.F_PRODUCT
LEFT JOIN 
    V_PROD_ALIAS_ICO IC ON TP.F_PRODUCT = IC.F_PRODUCT
LEFT JOIN 
    V_PROD_ALIAS_MANU MAN ON TP.F_PRODUCT = MAN.F_PRODUCT
LEFT JOIN 
    V_PROD_ALIAS_CASN CASN ON TP.F_PRODUCT = CASN.F_PRODUCT
```

Query after commenting out the column `MAN.F_PHRE AS MANU` takes three seconds to display 53,000 records.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    TP.PRODUCT AS ID,
    TP.NAME AS [NAME],
    TP.LANGUAGE AS LANGCODE,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, TP.F_DATE_REVISED, 120) AS RDATE,
    CASE
       WHEN NOT(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(TP.F_CAS_NUM,'¿',' '))),' ','; ') IS NULL OR REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(TP.F_CAS_NUM,'¿',' '))),' ','; ') = '') 
          THEN REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(TP.F_CAS_NUM,'¿',' '))),' ','; ') 
          ELSE REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(CASN.F_DATA,'¿',' '))),' ','; ')
    END AS CASNUM ,
    TP.F_CUSTOM1 AS cus1,
    TP.F_CUSTOM2 AS cus2,
    (SELECT TC.F_COUNTRY_NAME FROM COUNTRIES TC 
     WHERE TC.F_COUNTRY_CODE = TP.F_CUSTOM5) AS cus5,
    -- MAN.F_PHR AS MANU,
    CASE
       WHEN NOT(TP.F_CUSTOM3 IS NULL OR TP.F_CUSTOM3 = '') 
          THEN TP.F_CUSTOM3 
          ELSE SYN.F_DATA
    END AS SYN, 
    IC.F_DATA AS ICO,
    'SDS - ' + (SELECT TL.F_LAN_NAME FROM T_LANGUAGE TL 
                WHERE TL.F_LANGUAGE = TP.F_LANGUAGE) + ' - PDF' AS DOC,
    '' AS COVER,
    CAST(TP.F_GUID AS VARCHAR(36)) + '_PDF' AS [GUID],
    'PDF' AS SDS
FROM 
    PDF TP
LEFT JOIN 
    V_PROD_ALIAS_SYN SYN ON TP.F_PRODUCT = SYN.F_PRODUCT
LEFT JOIN 
    V_PROD_ALIAS_SITE SIT ON TP.F_PRODUCT = SIT.F_PRODUCT
LEFT JOIN 
    V_PROD_ALIAS_ICO IC ON TP.F_PRODUCT = IC.F_PRODUCT
LEFT JOIN 
    V_PROD_ALIAS_MANU MAN ON TP.F_PRODUCT = MAN.F_PRODUCT
LEFT JOIN 
    V_PROD_ALIAS_CASN CASN ON TP.F_PRODUCT = CASN.F_PRODUCT
```

Comment: What **datatype** is that column `MAN.F_PHRE` in the base table? And have you had a look at the **execution plans** for the two queries? Do you see any difference?

Comment: It is using NVARCHAR data type in the base table.I am using the above query in my stored procedure.

Comment: What **length**? `NVARCHAR(50)` or `NVARCHAR(MAX)` ?? The latter could be **up to 1 billion** characters - are you storing a really huge amount of text in this column?

Comment: The length is NVARCHAR(MAX).I checked the  max(len(f_phr)) in base table is 3425.

Comment: NVARCHAR(MAX) will reduce the performance?Suggest please

Comment: It *might* - first of all just for the amount of data that might need to be transferred (but with 3425 chars, that shouldn't be an issue), and because it supports up to 2 GB of data (1 billion characters), it's handling is slightly different than a "regular" `NVARCHAR(n)` column which also can slow down things (just a little bit)

Comment: OK.Thanks.Now i am creating one temp table in procedure and inserting the records from view(V_PROD_ALIAS_MANU MAN) into this temp table and used this temp table in left join instead of view(V_PROD_ALIAS_MANU MAN) in the select statement..will it improve performance?.